# check if filter is applied in Pivot Table using vba

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I'm looking for a way to check if filter was applied in a column of pivottable.

I tried this in a "normal" Excel table:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Dim count,l As Long
    Set wsh = ActiveSheet
    count = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "D").End(xlUp).Row 'because this column doesn't have empty rpws
On Error GoTo hide_dup

    If wsh.AutoFilter.Filters(1).On Or wsh.AutoFilter.Filters(2).On Then 'to see if col1 or 2 are filtered
        l = 1
        Do While l <= count
            my code....
    Else 
        ....mycode...
    End If
Exit Sub
hide_dup:
    ...my code...
End Sub
```

Now I want to do the same with a Pivot table but
`ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(1)` does not work with Pivot which is normal. So that is why I tried

````
If ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("col_name").PivotFilters = True Then```

and the same like the other code. But it does not seem to work because it goes to the **hide_dup-function** and when I remove **on error..** I get the run error [450][1] . Does someone Know how I can check if is there a applied filter in column of pivottable like i did with a normal table?

Any suggestions would be appreciated...


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/wrong-number-of-arguments-error-450
````

Comment: Try: `If ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("col_name").PivotFilters.Count > 0 Then`

Comment: @Rory first thanks for your suggestion. I tried it but it never goes in the if-statment but in the else-statment even when i set a filter an the **col_name**

Comment: I print that: ```ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("col_name").PivotFilters.Count``` with msgbox  to see if the count is matching with number of selected values in the column but I'm always getting 0

Comment: If you're manually selecting items from the available list, use the AllItemsVisible property of the field instead. If True, all are selected.

Comment: You'll need to combine both approaches if the user might be using the filter options as well as just selecting or deselecting items.

Comment: .PivotFilters.Count    it won't work if filter done by slicer